# Where can I see all my comments on issues on GitHub?

Tags: github, comments

Where can I see all the comments I wrote on issues on the GitHub website?

https://github.com/issues only list the issues I have opened, and not the issues I have commented on.

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Using the search box at the top of GitHub web pages, you can perform a variety of searches.
[image]

---

To view issues you've commented on use the following search string:
<sub>[*Sample Search URL*](https://github.com/search?q=is%3Aissue%20commenter%3A%40me&type=issues)</sub>

```
is:issue commenter:@me
```

---

To show only open issues, add the `is:open` qualifier:
<sub>[*Sample Search URL*](https://github.com/search?q=is%3Aissue%20commenter%3A%40me%20is%3Aopen&type=issues)</sub>

```
is:issue commenter:@me is:open
```

---

The search can also be adapted for any user by replacing `@me` with their GitHub `username`.  Do not include the `@` symbol in this case.

For example, for the username `defunkt`/`@defunkt` use:
<sub>[*Sample Search URL*](https://github.com/search?q=is%3Aissue%20commenter%3Adefunkt&type=issues)</sub>

```
is:issue commenter:defunkt
```

---

**Source:** [GitHub Docs, Searching issues and pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/)

Answer (score 97):

You can filter your subscribed notifications for only those where you commented on a thread, by selecting `Comment` as the `Reason` at [github.com/notifications/subscriptions](https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions) or by appending `?reason=comment` to the URL ([github.com/notifications/subscriptions?reason=comment](https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions?reason=comment)).

While you can only filter for a single `Reason` at a time, other available options include `Assign`, `Author`, `Manual`, `Mention`, `Review Requested`, `State Change`, `Team Mention`

You can use the `Repository` dropdown with or without `Reason` to filter notifications by a specific repository.

Answer (score 22):

Easier and improve from the accepted answer:
`is:issue commenter:@me`

Comment: freginold's answer was updated from comments in rev 6 such that it now includes this answer.

Answer (score 16):

**View all my comments on GitHub Issues**

Visit: https://github.com/issues?q=is%3Aissue+commenter%3A%40me+sort%3Aupdated-desc

**Explained**

- https://github.com/issues lists all issues on Gitub
- Filter by `is:issue commenter:@me sort:updated-desc`

  - `commenter:@me` dynamically always filters by the logged in user (you could also replace `@me` with your actual username)
  - `sort:updated-desc` the default sort is based on Newest which looks at issue creation date. Setting to sort by updated means issues with the most recent posts will appear first (this is what I expected the default to be)

Alternatively, https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions works as a decent proxy, but if you have unsubscribed to an issue it won't show here any more (thanks @guettli for this one).

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `involves:<username>` in the search bar of issues which consists of more issues than `commenter:<username>`

For instance, if you only create a new issue without any comments, the `involves` prefix considers it, but not `commenter`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search for multiple users in a single search, use it like in the global search bar without the `OR` logical conjugation:

`commenter:FantomX1 commenter:FantomX1-github`

since the similar google way approach with 'OR' would not work

**commenter:FantomX1 <s>OR</s> commenter:FantomX1-github**