# Where can I see all my comments at GitHub?

Tags: github

This following Thread gets me all my comments on **issues** at GitHub
[Where can I see all my comments on issues on GitHub?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103374/where-can-i-see-all-my-comments-on-issues-on-github?newreg=f43024c7d0cd41dda0af32c07a76b2de)
It does not get me my comments on **pull requests**.

I need something to get me all my comments at GitHub, or failing that my comments at GitHub on Pull requests would do.

Comment: @ARM32 Thx for reply and suggestion. I have not been able to get it to work yet. (BTW your link to the previous Thread in your answer don't work) Thx anyway. Alan ( I suppose this comment should go in ARM32 answer, But I aint alloed to. Perhaps someone who can could pass it on so he gets it? Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same search field the linked thread mentions (https://github.com/issues).

Remove `is:issue` from the search query (leaving only `commenter:username`) and the search results will also include pull requests.