# Is there a way to search through comments on issues on GitHub?

Tags: github

Last night at like 3 AM I made a comment on an issue that was pertinent to the problem I'm facing. Now I can't find what GitHub issue I made the comment on.

- Is there a way to see all the comments I've made on GitHub issues?
- Do GitHub Users have an activity feed?
- Can I search the comments I've made on GitHub?

It seems I can only do this with issues I **Created**, was **Assigned**, or am **Mentioned** in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find what I wanted not by looking for "feed" or searching, but here,

- https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions

GitHub calls them subscriptions. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see all the comments I've made on GitHub issues?

Yes, by searching `is:issue commenter:username`, where `username` is your username. ([Source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/104836/18147))